# Replace inner html on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replace, selected

I want to change content of a DIV that is outside carousel.

When you click on carousel DIV's it takes the content from its hidden DIV, and replaces the same in other DIV which is outside the carousel. Im some what creating something like this, see how title and description changes on selecting. http://bqworks.com/products/3d-carousel/example2.html

#### HTML

```
<div class="carousel"> <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->     
    <div class="slides"> <!-- BEGIN CAROUSEL -->
        <div class="slideItem">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/cars/orange.png" />
            </a>
            <p class="title">The HEAD 1</p>
            <p class="description">Some big big paragraph 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slideItem">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/cars/covered.png" />
            </a> 
            <p class="title">The HEAD 2</p>
            <p class="description">Some big big paragraph 2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slideItem">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/cars/orange.png" />
            </a>
            <p class="title">The HEAD 3</p>
            <p class="description">Some big big paragraph 3</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END SLIDES -->
</div><!-- carousel END -->

<div id="text">    
    <p id="selected-title">THIS SHOULD GET TITLE FROM ABOVE</p>    
    <p id="selected-description">Description of the selected item</p>    
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".slideItem").click(function() {
        var title = $('.title').html();
        var desc = $('.description').html();
        $('#text #selected-title').html.replace(title);
        $('#text #selected-description').html.replace(desc);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, consider getting appropriate `.title` and `.description` elements for each clicked `.slideItem` element. Finally, use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to replace the inner HTML:

```
$(".slideItem").click(function() {
    var title = $(this).find(".title").html();
    var desc = $(this).find(".description").html();
    $("#selected-title").html(title);
    $("#selected-description").html(desc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @PranayRana for replying, but other 2 answers are not helping me. But this one does works :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('#text #selected-title').html(title);
$('#text #selected-description').html(desc);
```

This will replace the html, if you want to append use `.append(title);`

Comment: this link also having same issue "html.(desc);"

Comment: This one won't work because `var title = $('.title').html();` still won't select the right `title` and the same for `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
$('#text #selected-title').html(title);
$('#text #selected-description').html(desc);
```

there is no need to use `replace` method to replace content

Comment: This one won't work because `var title = $('.title').html();` still won't select the right `title` and the same for `desc`.